# BEGIN and END in Sybase SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to unite a number of operations into one block in Sybase SQL, in the following way:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION MyInsert;
INSERT INTO dbo.Agencies (code, name) VALUES ( 1, 'My Group');
INSERT INTO dbo.Agencies (code, name) VALUES ( 2, 'Their Group');
COMMIT TRANSACTION MyInsert;
```

When the `INSERT` statements execute by themselves, they execute just fine and the rows are inserted. When I execute the block, I get the error

`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.`

I tried marking the block with `BEGIN` and `END` instead, like so:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO dbo.Agencies (code, name) VALUES ( 1, 'My Group');
INSERT INTO dbo.Agencies (code, name) VALUES ( 2, 'Their Group');
END;
```

and I am still getting the same error. How would this work in Sybase SQL?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon, Sybase doesn't need it

Comment: @OfirW Removing it does not solve my problem (I tried). It does not hurt to have it there and makes the language more standard.

Comment: It doesn't work for me with the semicolon in the begin and end part

Comment: @OfirW it does not work for me with or without the semicolon :-), only if I remove both the `BEGIN` and `END` completely. Is there a way to define this block as a transaction?

Comment: What happens if you just put an empty transaction: `begin tran commit tran` ?

Comment: @OfirW figured it out - it was a problem with SQL Developer, your suggestion works fine in other tools. Write it up as an answer and I will be happy to both upvote and accept. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment: Remove the semicolons - Sybase doesn't like them